# add a row to an empty array in python

Tags: python, arrays, is-empty, vstack

I would lie to add an array to an empty array in numpy.
Basically I would like to do the following:

```
AA = np.array([])


for i in range(0,3):
    # 
    BB = np.random.rand(3)
    CC = np.vstack((AA, BB))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 3
```

I would like to avoid introducing an if clause. An idea could be to use "np.zeros(3)" to set-up AA and then remove the first row.

What do you think? I do like the second option either.

Thanks

Comment: the code in its current state is senseless: `AA` is static and is not changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.empty` to make an array with a set size:

```
AA = np.empty((0, 3))
```

This gives an array with one empty dimension and one dimension of size 3, so it is possible to `vstack` it with your proposed `BB` array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `np.append` instead of `np.vstack`? You could then try something like this:

```
AA = np.array([])

for i in range(0,3):
    BB = np.random.rand(3)
    # Use np.append to append BB to AA along the first axis
    AA = np.append(AA, BB)

# Reshape AA into a 2D array with 3 columns
AA = AA.reshape(-1, 3)

# AA should now contain the concatenated arrays
```